# How to join two list of objects into one in java

Tags: java

Hi i have two ArrayList of objects and i need to merge it as a single list. Here is my requirement

My firstList

ListA

```
{StaffFirstName=f2, resourceId=2, totalcost=18055.0, totalPercentageInvolvment=550, ResourceCost=2300, staffRole=tl}
```

and listB

```
{sixthmonth=60, fourthmonth=40, firstmonth=10, fifthmonth=50, secondmonth=20, `thirdmonth=30}`
```

and i need the result to be

Result

```
{StaffFirstName=f2, resourceId=2, totalcost=18055.0, totalPercentageInvolvment=550, ResourceCost=2300, staffRole=tl, sixthmonth=60, fourthmonth=40, firstmonth=10, fifthmonth=50, secondmonth=20, thirdmonth=30}
```

**EDIT!**

Actually my Both list are arrayList so my listA will be

```
{StaffFirstName=f2, resourceId=2, totalcost=18055.0, totalPercentageInvolvment=550, ResourceCost=2300, staffRole=tl}
{StaffFirstName=demo35, resourceId=3, totalcost=19625.0, totalPercentageInvolvment=785, ResourceCost=2500, staffRole=sweeper}
```

and list B will be

```
{sixthmonth=100, fourthmonth=30, firstmonth=40, fifthmonth=25, secondmonth=100, thirdmonth=90}
{sixthmonth=100, fourthmonth=30, firstmonth=40, fifthmonth=25, secondmonth=100, thirdmonth=90}
```

and the result should be

```
{StaffFirstName=f2, resourceId=2, totalcost=18055.0, totalPercentageInvolvment=550, ResourceCost=2300, staffRole=tl, sixthmonth=60, fourthmonth=40, firstmonth=10, fifthmonth=50, secondmonth=20, thirdmonth=30}
{StaffFirstName=demo35, resourceId=3, totalcost=19625.0, totalPercentageInvolvment=785, ResourceCost=2500, staffRole=sweeper, sixthmonth=100, fourthmonth=30, firstmonth=40, fifthmonth=25, secondmonth=100, thirdmonth=90}
```

That means each row of my tow list must be append my row wise. If i use `addAll` function the two list just append like this

```
{StaffFirstName=f2, resourceId=2, totalcost=18055.0, totalPercentageInvolvment=550, ResourceCost=2300, staffRole=tl}
{StaffFirstName=demo35, resourceId=3, totalcost=19625.0, totalPercentageInvolvment=785, ResourceCost=2500, staffRole=sweeper}
{sixthmonth=60, fourthmonth=40, firstmonth=10, fifthmonth=50, secondmonth=20, thirdmonth=30}
{sixthmonth=100, fourthmonth=30, firstmonth=40, fifthmonth=25, secondmonth=100, thirdmonth=90}. But i need to append the two list row wise. Is it possible?
```

Comment: Yah it is arrayList of objects.

Comment: @LukasEder, `"StaffFirstName=f2"` :-)

Comment: I have explain the question in more detail. Please check.

Comment: yah my list is a list of objects.

Comment: Can you give us the code instead of the weird JSON-like notation?  As another commenter mentioned, it looks more like you've got a bunch of maps here rather than lists.

Answer (score 9):

Given:

```
   List<MyClass> listA, listB;
```

Try this:

```
   List<MyClass> union = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
   union.addAll( listA );
   union.addAll( listB );
```

**EDIT (Java 8 or later)**

In Java 8 or later, you can use streams to join the lists in a single expression.

```
List<MyClass> union = Stream.concat( listA.stream(), listB.stream())
            .collect( Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure that what you have is an `ArrayList` (from the output), but even so, if it's a class that implements the `Collection` interface, you can use the `addAll` method, independent of the exact class (as long as the objects are of the same type).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection, T...)

Answer (score 2):

If these are ArrayList<> objects containing the same type, you can use this:

```
list1.addAll(list2);
```

and it should work fine for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Type is the type of array....

```
 Type[] concat(Type[] listA, Type[] listB) 
     {
       Type[] list= new Type[listA.length+listB.length];
       System.arraycopy(listA, 0, list, 0, listA.length);
       System.arraycopy(listB, 0, list, listA.length, listB.length);

       return list;
     }
```